# Parsing a string with nested quotes

Tags: python, quotes, string-parsing

I need to parse a string that looks like this:

```
"prefix 'field1', '', 'field2', 'field3', 'select ... where (column1 = '2017') and ((('literal1', 'literal2', 'literal3', 'literal4', 'literal5', 'literal6', 'literal7') OVERLAPS column2 Or ('literal8') OVERLAPS column3 And (column4 > 0.0 Or column6 > 0.0)) And column7 IN_COMMUNITY [int1] And column5 = 'literal9')  LIMIT 0 ', 'field5', 'field6', 'field7', 'field8', 'field9', '', 'field10'"
```

And I would like to get a list like the following:

```
['field1', '', 'field2', 'field3', 'select ... where (column1 = '2017') and ((('literal1', 'literal2', 'literal3', 'literal4', 'literal5', 'literal6', 'literal7') OVERLAPS column2 Or ('literal8') OVERLAPS column3 And" (column4 > 0.0 Or column6 > 0.0)) And column7 IN_COMMUNITY [int1] And column5 = 'literal9')  LIMIT 0 ', 'field5', 'field6', 'field7', 'field8', 'field9', '', 'field10']
```

I've tried it with regular expressions, but it doesn't work in the substring of the pseudo-SQL statement.

How can I get that list?

Comment: The bottom example isn't terminated correctly when you put it in a script, so I don't know exactly how you want to chop this up. There's also a rogue " after 'column3 And' which means there are 3 double quotes. How should these line up?

Comment: I fixed the string. I'd like to get a list where each field in the string was a field in the list including the substring starts with select and ends with LIMIT 0.

Comment: Is the SQL part correct? it contains a rogue quote in `OVERLAPS column3  And"`. Also, is the number of fields constant?

Comment: I don't think this is possible if the input string contains **arbitratry** sql statements, since those could contain any number of embedded quotes and commas.

Comment: If the number of fields is constant, you could extract the fields to the left side of the query and the fields to the right side of the query and then whatever remains is the sql query.

Comment: @solarc Yes - by "arbitrary", I meant any number of sql statements anywhere in the input string. Which I suppose is another way of asking whether the input string has a fixed structure. Another issue is: what exactly is in the other fields? Presumably it's not literally "field1", "field2", etc.

Comment: @solarc yes, the number of fields are constant and will have just one pseudosql statement.

Comment: @ekhumoro In the other fields there are free text but they don't contain quotes inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a brittle way to do it if you know what the SQL string is supposed to look like.

We match the SQL string, and split the rest into start and end strings.

Then we match the simpler field pattern and build up a list from start for that pattern, add back in the SQL match, and then the fields from the end string.

```
sqlmatch = 'select .* LIMIT 0'
fieldmatch = "'(|\w+)'"
match = re.search(sqlmatch, mystring)
startstring = mystring[:match.start()]
sql = mystring[match.start():match.end()]
endstring = mystring[match.end():]
result = []
for found in re.findall(fieldmatch, startstring):
    result.append(found)

result.append(sql)
for found in re.findall(fieldmatch, endstring):
    result.append(found)
```

Then the result list looks like the following:

```
['field1',
 '',
 'field2',
 'field3',
 'select ... where (column1 = \'2017\') and (((\'literal1\', \'literal2\', \'literal3\', \'literal4\', \'literal5\', \'literal6\', \'literal7\') OVERLAPS column2 Or (\'literal8\') 
OVERLAPS column3 And" (column4 > 0.0 Or column6 > 0.0)) And column7 IN_COMMUNITY [int1] And column5 = \'literal9\')  LIMIT 0',
 'field5',
 'field6',
 'field7',
 'field8',
 'field9',
 '',
 'field10']
```

Comment: This doesn't preserve empty strings per the examples (although that doesn't necessarily mean the OP needs them)

Answer (score 1):

Since the number of fields is fixed and the non-sql fields do not have embedded quotes, there is a simple, three-line solution:

```
prefix, other = string.partition(' ')[::2]
fields = other.strip('\'').split('\', \'')
fields[4:-7] = [''.join(fields[4:-7])]

print(fields)
```

Output:

```
['field1', '', 'field2', 'field3', "select ... where (column1 = '2017') and ((('literal1literal2literal3literal4literal5literal6literal7') OVERLAPS column2 Or ('literal8') OVERLAPS column3 And (column4 > 0.0 Or column6 > 0.0)) And column7 IN_COMMUNITY [int1] And column5 = 'literal9')  LIMIT 0 ", 'field5', 'field6', 'field7', 'field8', 'field9', '', 'field10']
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone pointed out your string is malformed, I used this:

```
mystr = "prefix 'field1', '', 'field2', 'field3', 'select ... where (column1 = '2017') and ((('literal1', 'literal2', 'literal3', 'literal4', 'literal5', 'literal6', 'literal7') OVERLAPS column2 Or ('literal8') OVERLAPS column3 And" (column4 > 0.0 Or column6 > 0.0)) And column7 IN_COMMUNITY [int1] And column5 = 'literal9')  LIMIT 0 ', 'field5', 'field6', 'field7', 'field8', 'field9', '', 'field10'"

found = [a.replace("'", '').replace(',', '') for a in mystr.split(' ') if "'" in a]
```

Which returns:

```
['field1',
 '',
 'field2',
 'field3',
 'select',
 '2017)',
 '(((literal1',
 'literal2',
 'literal3',
 'literal4',
 'literal5',
 'literal6',
 'literal7)',
 '(literal8)',
 'literal9)',
 '',
 'field5',
 'field6',
 'field7',
 'field8',
 'field9',
 '',
 'field10']
```

Comment: Your output doesn't look like what the OP requested. The select statement shouldn't be broken up at all.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of fields is constant, you could do something like this:

```
def splitter(string):
    strip_chars = "\"' "
    string = string[len('prefix '):] # remove the prefix
    left_parts = string.split(',', 4) # only split up to 4 times
    for i in left_parts[:-1]:
        yield i.strip(strip_chars) # return what we've found so far
    right_parts = left_parts[-1].rsplit(',', 7) # only split up to 7 times starting from the right
    for i in right_parts:
        yield i.strip(strip_chars) # return the rest

mystr = """prefix 'field1', '', 'field2', 'field3', 'select ... where (column1 = '2017') and ((('literal1', 'literal2', 'literal3', 'literal4', 'literal5', 'literal6', 'literal7') OVERLAPS column2 Or ('literal8') OVERLAPS column3 And" (column4 > 0.0 Or column6 > 0.0)) And column7 IN_COMMUNITY [int1] And column5 = 'literal9')  LIMIT 0 ', 'field5', 'field6', 'field7', 'field8', 'field9', '', 'field10'"""
result = list(splitter(mystr))
print(repr(result))


# result:
[
    'field1',
    '',
    'field2',
    'field3',
    'select ... where (column1 = \'2017\') and (((\'literal1\', \'literal2\', \'literal3\', \'literal4\', \'literal5\', \'literal6\', \'literal7\') OVERLAPS column2 Or (\'literal8\') OVERLAPS column3 And" (column4 > 0.0 Or column6 > 0.0)) And column7 IN_COMMUNITY [int1] And column5 = \'literal9\')  LIMIT 0',
    'field5',
    'field6',
    'field7',
    'field8',
    'field9',
    '',
    'field10'
]
```

Comment: If the rest of the fields can contain commas, then it would need a parser instead of the simple split.

Answer (score 0):

The comma separators that are actually between fields will be at an even quote level.  So, by changing these commas to \n characters, you could apply a simple .split("\n") on the string to get field values.  You then only need to clean up the field values to remove leading/trailing spaces and quotes.

```
from itertools import accumulate

string      = "prefix 'field1', '', 'field2', 'field3', 'select ... where (column1 = '2017') and ((('literal1', 'literal2', 'literal3', 'literal4', 'literal5', 'literal6', 'literal7') OVERLAPS column2 Or ('literal8') OVERLAPS column3 And (column4 > 0.0 Or column6 > 0.0)) And column7 IN_COMMUNITY [int1] And column5 = 'literal9')  LIMIT 0 ', 'field5', 'field6', 'field7', 'field8', 'field9', '', 'field10'"
prefix,data = string.split(" ",1)                   # remove prefix
quoteLevels = accumulate( c == "'" for c in data )  # compute quote levels for each character
fieldData   = "".join([ "\n" if c=="," and q%2 == 0 else c for c,q in zip(data,quoteLevels) ]) # comma to /n at even quote levels
fields      = [ f.strip().strip("'") for f in fieldData.split("'\n '") ] # split and clean content

for i,field in enumerate(fields): print(i,field)
```

This will print:

```
0 field1
1 
2 field2
3 field3
4 select ... where (column1 = '2017') and ((('literal1', 'literal2', 'literal3', 'literal4', 'literal5', 'literal6', 'literal7') OVERLAPS column2 Or ('literal8') OVERLAPS column3 And (column4 > 0.0 Or column6 > 0.0)) And column7 IN_COMMUNITY [int1] And column5 = 'literal9')  LIMIT 0 
5 field5
6 field6
7 field7
8 field8
9 field9
10 
11 field10
```

Comment: This won't work in cases where the fields contain quotes or commas. eg. if `'literal1'` was instead `'bob,dole'` or `'bob\'s'`.

Comment: That would only be an issue if an embedded quoted text contained a comma or a field contained an unbalanced quote. A field merely containing a comma would not be a problem. In any case, speculating beyond the example provided is a bit pointless given that the data format is riddled with potential inconsistencies that will not allow it to support a full spectrum of text content

Comment: I don't disagree, I just think it's worth noting limitations on solutions: should someone else come along who does need those capabilities, it will help them from heading down the wrong path. And [it will fail if any of the literal fields contain a comma](https://repl.it/repls/AngryGrimMatrix). It relies on those literal strings to not contain a comma, as the parsing is off at that depth.